# Can't access drupal 6 pages after migration

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Please I just moved a drupal 6 site from a Suse Linux server where its working well to a Mac lion server where i have set up a test domain for it. I have successfully imported the existing database and configured settings.php with exactly the same database name, username, password and server name.
when i enter the url of the test domain on the server, I can see the index page of the site but when i click on any of the links, i get an error message like this one "The requested URL /content/about was not found on this server."

Please does anyone have an idea on how i can solve this problem? I copied the entire sites folder and database including the .htaccess folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to access the internal pages using `?q=`. e.g. `site.com/?q=admin`. And disable clear URL.

Make sure you have uploaded drupal's default `.htaccess` file to your websites root. Apparently because you worked on MAC, you forgot to upload the `.htaccess` file, because it's hidden by default.

Hope this helps.